# Find count of String in hundred column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have hundred data in spreadsheet. I want to know the count of that fruit name. How can i do this in Spreadsheet?
Example (expected) output:

```
Banana = 38
Grape = 41
Dates = 29
Orange = 32
..
etc
```

[image: spreadsheet]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QUERY()` would be good choice.

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(B2:J),"select Col1, count(Col1) group by Col1 label Col1 'Fruits', count(Col1) 'Count'")
```

If you want to exclude blank cells then use

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(B2:J),"select Col1, count(Col1) 
where (Col1 is not null) 
group by Col1 
label Col1 'Fruits', count(Col1) 'Count'")
```

[image]

Comment: Dada, super formula!